# Enable only saturdays and last day in the year with jQuery Datepicker

Tags: jquery

I want to enable only saturdays, and last day in year (31.12) in jQuery Datepicker, so far i enabled only saturdays, but i can't get to enable 31.12. in each year.
My code:

```
<script>
  function datepick()
{
    var weekend_strtday = 1;
    var dva = 2;
    var tri = 3;
    var cetiri = 4;
    var pet = 0;
    var weekend_endday =  5;
    $('#datum').datepicker({
        firstDay: 1,
        minDate: 0,
        dateFormat: 'yy-mm-dd',
       beforeShowDay: function(date) {
         var day1 = date.getDay();
         return [(day1 != weekend_strtday && day1 != weekend_endday && day1 != dva && day1 != tri && day1 != cetiri && day1 != pet)];
        }
    });


 }
datepick();
</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this example:

Saturdays can be simplified to day 6, or the month and date is Dec 31.

```js
function datepick()
{
    $('#datum').datepicker({
        firstDay: 1,
        minDate: 0,
        dateFormat: 'yy-mm-dd',
        beforeShowDay: function(date) {
            var day = date.getDay();

                 // Saturdays  or  Dec 31st
            return [(day == 6) || ((date.getMonth() + 1) == 12 && date.getDate() == 31)];
        }
    });
}
datepick();
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>

Date: <input class="form-control" id="datum"></input>
```

Comment: Thank you very much